# Sending A Class Packet

Tags: c#, networking, multiplayer

How would I be able to send a class through the internet like this.

```
class Player
{
    public int Health;
    public Player Copy()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And do this.

```
SendPacket(new Player);
```

Well something like that?

Comment: Look up **serialization**.

Comment: Doh I didn't realize I was on the gamedev section. This question would be a better fit for stackexchange.com since it is a general programming question not a game related question. However I can't flag it for move (has that been changed?).

Comment: @RoyT Pretty sure those kinds of flags just turn into close votes now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do two things.

First you have to be able to serialize your object. The definition, according to MSDN is:

> Serialization is the process of converting an object into a stream of
>   bytes in order to store the object or transmit it to memory, a
>   database, or a file. Its main purpose is to save the state of an
>   object in order to be able to recreate it when needed. The reverse
>   process is called deserialization.

You can find many ways to do this in C# but I would recommend to use the built in binary serialization techniques in .NET. You can start reading up on that here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx

Then you have to make some sort of connection. Between two computers. One way to do this is using sockets. Microsoft has made this quite easy in .NET (although I think in Java it is slightly easier but less flexible). To keep it simple I would suggest using Synchronous Sockets first. Synchronous means that the program 'hangs' until all the data has been received by the other party. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xt5x5zw.aspx

If you don't want the program to hang while sending the data you can use Asynchronous Sockets. They are a lot harder to use because you have to explicitly tell the other end how much data to expect and you have to handle the several steps the sending takes. I found the MSDN tutorial on this a bit unclear but you can find them for client and server [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx). I also wrote my own tutorial which you can find [here](http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2012/09/09/c-asynchronous-sockets-revisited/) and if you try Google you will see there are a lot more so skim a few and then pick the one that you find explains it best.

Recap

1. Serialize the object
2. Send the bytes using a socket
3. Receive the bytes on the other end
4. Deserialize and we have reconstructed the object on another computer :)